# Same function for all columns in DataFrame

Tags: pandas, loops, for-loop, iteration, calculated-columns

My data contains 75 columns. I want to calculate below function for all columns seperatly and want to write a dataframe.

My data's columns,

```
df3.columns

Index(['R_26', 'R_31', 'R_38', 'R_65', 'R_71', 'R_86', 'R_25', 'R_63', 'R_59',
   'R_19', 'R_35', 'R_84', 'R_24', 'R_68', 'S_15', 'R_85', 'R_57', 'R_22',
   'R_30', 'R_15', 'R_16', 'R_69', 'S_16', 'R_6', 'R_87', 'R_40', 'R_20',
   'R_17', 'R_18', 'R_21', 'R_28', 'S_9', 'R_33', 'R_56', 'S_10', 'R_7',
   'S_8', 'R_29', 'R_1', 'R_66', 'S_18', 'S_6', 'R_64', 'R_34', 'R_37',
   'R_3', 'R_54', 'R_67', 'S_22', 'R_13', 'R_48', 'S_11', 'R_58', 'S_23',
   'S_3', 'S_4', 'R_60', 'S_7', 'R_32', 'S_5', 'R_51', 'R_8', 'R_10',
   'R_9', 'S_14', 'R_62', 'S_17', 'S_21', 'R_14', 'R_55', 'R_2', 'R_50',
   'R_49', 'R_53', 'FRAUD'],
  dtype='object')
```

My function (doing for just 1 sample 'R_26');

```
df4 = df3[df3.R_26 == 1]
Sm = df4.R_26.sum()
Fr = df4.FRAUD.sum()
Rate = b / a
```

As i want data frame sample;

---

Column                            Rate

---

R_26                              0.15
R_31                              0.45
.                                 .
.                                 .
.                                 .

Comment: `Rate = b / a` is `Rate = Fr / Sm` or `Rate = Sm/ Fr` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) for unpivot, then filter `1` values by [`DataFrame.query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html), aggregate `sum`, create `Rate` column by [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) with [`Series.div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.div.html) for divide and [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) for extract columns and last convert index to column by [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df = (df3.melt('FRAUD')
        .query('value == 1')
        .groupby('variable')
        .sum()
        .assign(Rate = lambda x: x.pop('FRAUD').div(x.pop('value')))
        .reset_index())
print (df)
```

Comment: maestro, what is `x.pop('FRAUD')` doing here ?

Comment: @YOLO - it is something like use column and drop, so instead `drop` both columns later it is drop with pop

Comment: @jezrael i need ask you to one more question. If i want to use 2 different function like below (sum and count), how should i edit your code?   df4 = df3[df3.R_26 == 1]
Sm = df4.R_26.count()
Fr = df4.FRAUD.sum()
Rate = b / a

Comment: @MertTürkyılmaz - Can you check to change `.groupby('variable').sum()`  to `.groupby('variable').agg({'value':'size','FRAUD':'sum'})` ?